# Palindrome Or Not (SPOJ) Java

Tags: java, input

I am trying to solve this problem in SPOJ: https://www.spoj.com/problems/PLNDROME/

When I run my program in IntelliJ it works fine but, when I send the code to SPOJ it doesn't work. I think that I have a problem with the input, I was reading the other similar solutions for this problem but those don't work for me. I always got the wrong answer.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in), 10 * 1024 * 1024);
        int T = Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());
        int a = 0;
        while(a++ < T){
            int N = Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());
            StringBuilder sb =   new StringBuilder(r.readLine());
            int M = Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());
            System.out.println("Case " + (a) + ":");
            while(M-- > 0){
                String  lines = r.readLine();
                String[] strs = lines.trim().split("\\s+");
                int i = Integer.parseInt(strs[0]);
                sb.setCharAt(i-1,strs[1].charAt(0));
                System.out.println(sb.toString().equals(sb.reverse().toString()) ? "YES" : "NO");
            }
        }
        r.close();
    }
}
```

ideone.com result:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

I hope to find someone that has the solution or the answer to this (First ask on Stack Overflow, blessings)

Comment: Hi @Samuel, welcome to stack overflow. Please check this guide on how to ask a good question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind the **run-time error** on Ideone is the empty input data stream (`STDIN`). Try to execute your program with the following input data (if you're going to use Ideone you can provide input data below the source code area):

```
1
11
madamimadam
6
6 z
1 a
11 b
5 z
1 b
7 z
```

As you can see (https://ideone.com/7c8E4y) it works fine for this data set.